# C++ How to get subfolder names stored in a String array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, directory

So, I need to get the names of n number of subfolders (located on a USB flash drive) from a set folder, and store them in a String array. It would need to automatically set its size to the number of subfolders prior to storing the names.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: C++ does not yet have a standard way of interacting with the file system.  You will need to look into boost or something else 3rd party.  Also, does it have to be an array?  You could use a vector.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have clarified my question

Comment: Oh wait I understand what you mean now. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you want just the sub folders, or the subfolders of subfolders?  Is there a depth requirement?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the folders in a specified path (i.e. E:/School)

Comment: hmm, [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)? Anyway it seems that the question is more about data structures manipulating than about a particular library.

Comment: Feel free to show what code you already wrote so far, and why exactly it doesn't work, that you can't figure it out by yourself. The direct answer to the question "How can I accomplish this" is "just write the code to do it".

Comment: I didn't mean "just write the code to do it", I meant more along the lines of "where can I get started on this?" Because I don't know C++ that well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a boost implementation, that gathers all of the sub directories of a specified directory, and stores them into a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    path p (".");//<- The path you want to get sub-folders of

    directory_iterator end_itr;

    // cycle through the directory
    std::vector<std::string> dirs;
    for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
    {
        if (is_directory(itr->path())) {
            dirs.push_back(itr->path().string());
        }
    }

    //at this point,
    //"dirs" contains strings to all of the sub folders.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! These are the errors I get when I try to use it: (Separated by |)
Cannot open include file: 'boost/filesystem.hpp': No such file or directory | 
identifier "is_directory" is undefined  | 
namespace "std" has no member "vector" | 
identifier "directory_iterator" is undefined | 
identifier "path" is undefined Get File Paths Test | 
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name | 
cannot open source file "boost/filesystem.hpp" |

Comment: @Spencer4134 You need to download/install the boost library and then link with it.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me a link to the download? @TrevorHickey

Comment: K I installed it, but it still gives me those errors. Please include in your answer how I am to go about implementing the above code @Trevor

Comment: You probably have to set your include paths, and link to the right libraries.  These would be flags that you send to the compiler.

Comment: While I feel this was a bit of an incomplete answer (Not including how-to's), I finally got this working. Thanks! (P.S. you forgot to put '<string>' after 'std::vector')

Answer (score 0):

As other comments mentioned, C++ core as a language does not have a mechanism for Filesystem operations. However, work is ongoing to add this (Refer http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=63483), based on Boost.

Meanwhile, using the Win32 API - you can do like below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

On Linux using the readdir API:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-System-Interface.html#File-System-Interface